# How to send bluemix wav stream response from java

Tags: java, text-to-speech, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, ibm-watson

I'd like to invoke IBM Bluemix service (say Text to Speech) from my Java code.
I've managed to get service credentials and URL but how can I invoke it after?

I've seen some example where people have used similar to below code but wondering how it works for a Text to Speech where it outputs a wav stream.

```
  String profileString = ex.execute(profileRequest)
         .handleResponse(new ResponseHandler<String>() {
    @Override
     public String handleResponse(HttpResponse r)
      throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
      }
    }
```

Can any one suggest on priority please?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/text-to-speech/api/v1/#introduction

Comment: I agree but using java how can I get hold of response which is coming in the format of audio/wav, audio/ogg stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link below has a Java code example of how to use the Watson text-to-speech service.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech-java

You should be looking for something like this from the `DemoServlet.java` class:

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (req.getParameter("text") == null || req.getParameter("voice") == null) {
            req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        } else {
            boolean download = false;
            if (req.getParameter("download") != null && req.getParameter("download").equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                download = true;
            }

            req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            try {
                String queryStr = req.getQueryString();
                String url = baseURL + "/v1/synthesize";
                if (queryStr != null) {
                    url += "?" + queryStr;
                }
                URI uri = new URI(url).normalize();

                Request newReq = Request.Get(uri);
                newReq.addHeader("Accept", "audio/ogg; codecs=opus");

                Executor executor = Executor.newInstance().auth(username, password);
                Response response = executor.execute(newReq);
                if (download)
                {
                    resp.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=transcript.ogg");
                }
                ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
                response.returnResponse().getEntity()
                .writeTo(servletOutputStream);
                servletOutputStream.flush();
                servletOutputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Log something and return an error message
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "got error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                resp.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_GATEWAY);
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, the link below has instructions on how to create a Java war file and deploy to Bluemix:

https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/getting_started/gs-full-java.shtml

Comment: Fantastic and this is what I'm looking for. Will flushed data gets played automatically on the client side i.e., say in Chrome browser?

Comment: Yes, I believe so - it should work for Chrome and Firefox.